# Display only the status from Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

I need to display only the status from the below command.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "infidltetl" -ScriptBlock {Get-Service -Name "Informatica 10.2.2" | Select-Object -Property Status}
```

Current output:

```
Status  PSComputerName RunspaceId                          
------  -------------- ----------                          
Running infidltetl     e3878de0-d931-480b-b637-b8957301c933
```

I  want to print only the value under the status property (Running/Not started etc.) But from the above command, it prints other values which I don't want.

Thanks.

Comment: `{(Get-Service -Name "Informatica 10.2.2" | Select-Object -Property Status).Status}`

Comment: `(Get-Service -Name "Informatica 10.2.2").Status` or `Get-Service -Name "Informatica 10.2.2" | Select-Object -Expand Status`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried your code. It just displays the same code again without doing anything.

Comment: The `PSComputerName` and presumably also the `RunspaceId` property are added by `Invoke-Command`, so you need to `| Select-Object Status` or `| Select-Object -Expand Status` after the `Invoke-Command`.

Answer (score 1):

Using this works for me:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName HOST_NAME -ScriptBlock {
    Get-Service -Name SERVICE_NAME
} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Status
```